# Pythonic, elegant way of dynamically defining a list of statically defined functions?

Tags: python, dynamic, scripting, static

I have only started learning Python recently. Let me explain what I am trying to accomplish. I have this .py script that basically has several functions (hard-coded into the script) that all need to be added to a single list, so that I can get the function I require by simply using the index operator as follows:

needed_function = function_list[needed_function_index]

My first attempt at implementing this resulted in the following code structure:

```
(imports)
function_list = []
(other global variables)

def function_0 = (...)
function_list.append(function_0)

def function_1 = (...)
function_list.append(function_1)

def function_2 = (...)
function_list.append(function_2)

(rest of code)
```

But I don't like that solution since it isn't very elegant. My goal is to be able to simply add the function definition to the script (without the append call) and the script will automatically add it to the list of functions.

I've thought of defining all the functions within another function, but I don't think I'd get anywhere with those. I thought of maybe "tagging" each function with a decorator but I realized that decorators (if I understand them correctly) are called every time a function is called, and not just once.

After some time I came up with this solution:

```
(imports)
(global variables)

def function_0 = (...)

def function_1 = (...)

def function_2 = (...)

function_list= [globals()[x] for x in globals() if re.match('^function_[0-9]+$', x)]

(rest of code)
```

I like it a bit more as a solution, but my only qualm with it is that I would prefer, for cleanliness purposes, to completely define function_list at the top of the script. However, I cannot do that since an invocation of globals() at the top of the script would not contain the functions since they have not been defined yet.

Perhaps I should simply settle for a less elegant solution, or maybe I am not writing my script in an idiomatic way. Whatever the case, any input and suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: My suggestion would be to do this with a decorator - I think that would be the most elegant. They are only run once.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are mistaken about decorators.  They are invoked once when the function is defined, and the function they return is then the value assigned to the function name, and it is that function that is invoked each time.  You can do what you want in a decorator without incurring runtime overhead.

```
my_functions = []

def put_in_list(fn):
    my_functions.append(fn)
    return fn

@put_in_list
def function1():
    pass

@put_in_list
def function2():
    pass
```

PS: You probably don't need to worry about runtime overhead anyway.

PPS: You are also trying to optimize odd things, you might be better off simply maintaining a list in your file.  How often are you adding functions, and with how little thought?  A list is not difficult to update in the source file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That's perfect.

I realize that this may seem like an odd optimization to make - optimizing my script's performance is not my goal, seeing as it's quite a simple script that's already fast. I just have this obsessive tendency to try to write the most beautiful and idiomatic code, something that might come in handy once I start taking on more complicated projects.

Answer (score 1):

Example of using a decorator that does not add any overhead to the function call:

```
my_list = []

def add_to_my_list(func):
    print 'decorator called'
    my_list.append(func)
    return func

@add_to_my_list
def foo():
    print 'foo called'

@add_to_my_list
def bar():
    print 'foo called'

print '-- done defining functions --'
my_list[0]()
my_list[1]()
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this problem would be to put all those functions into a single container, then extract the functions from the container to build your list.

The most Pythonic container would be a `class`.  I'm not saying to make them member functions of the class; just define them in the class.

```
class MyFunctions(object):
    def func0():
        pass
    def func1():
        pass

lst_funcs = [x for x in MyFunctions.__dict__ if not x.startswith('_')]
```

But I like the decorator approach even better; that's probably the most Pythonic solution.